# Why is my Python code making a duplicate file along an identical filepath?

Tags: python, pytube

I'm using the pytube library to download audio off Youtube videos and place the audio file right into my iTunes (Apple Music app) library. But, when I specify the filepath, it duplicates the "Media" folder and writes my download in that folder, despite there being a folder of the same name at the same location.

Here is my code:

```
import pytube

link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya8N9FhMq5s" 
song = "Angel (Massive Attack Cover).mp4"
track_num = "01 "
music_folder = "/Users/martinreid/Music/Music/Media/Automatically Add to Music"

yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
audio = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
dl_loc = audio.download(output_path=music_folder, filename=song, filename_prefix=track_num, skip_existing=True)

print("Download complete. File at: ", dl_loc)
```

So when I run this, and I look in Finder where the Media folder is (with all my downloaded songs), there are now two Media folders, identically named.

Why is this?

I have checked for misspellings or additional spaces in my filepath string, and everything seems to be correct.

Comment: "So when I run this, and I look in Finder where the Media folder is (with all my downloaded songs), there are now two Media folders, identically named." - run `import os; print(os.listdir('/Users/martinreid/Music/Music'))` and show us the output.

Comment: What do you mean "two Media folders?"  It's not possible to have two subfolders with identical names.

Comment: I thought the same thing as you two. I ran my code with the code user2357112 requested at the end. Here is the result of the requested line: ```['Media.localized', '.DS_Store', 'Music Library.musiclibrary', 'Media']```

Comment: Here's a screenshot from Finder, what I saw and why I mentioned two media folders: https://imgur.com/a/Zag9xj0

Comment: Sounds like you've got your Finder configured to hide the `.localized` extension.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to account for this in a filepath in python code, so I put my files in the original Media folder, and not create a localized copy of it?

Comment: @user2357112 Also, why does it do this?

Comment: Are you sure that Python is writing to the `Media.localized` folder, or is the original Media folder the one with the `.localized` extension?

Comment: @NickODell it looks like, after a little playing around with that ```listdir()``` function, that the original folder is ```Media.localized```. after adding ```.localized``` to my filepath where needed, it's working as expected!